# How to make Financial Times faceted charts with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Financial Times have a nice faceted coronavirus chart: see Daily death tolls at https://www.ft.com/coronavirus-latest Do you have an idea how make it using R and ggplot2?

[image: Financial Times chart]

Facet_wrap function is not useful in this case, it separates every country line to single minigraphs. The other countries are not visible in gray.

Should I prepare 20+ charts and join them using gridExtra::grid.arrange()?

Comment: check out the `gghighlight` package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gghighlight/vignettes/gghighlight.html

Comment: Thanks, it looks useful, I will try it.

Comment: `grid.arrange` might be a good way to achieve this though I doubt you could get exactly the same graph. First you could build a function with parameter country name. f(country) would generate a plot with the highlighted country and the country name. Then you could loop through all the countries and arrange the grid. Need some data to be more precise could you find that?

Comment: gghighlight is really great package for this. I can make this charts adding one row gghighlight() to the ggplot code only.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking whether there's way to plot the above without replicating the data.frame, so I simulate some data:

```
set.seed(111)
data = data.frame(group=rep(letters[1:6],each=60),
do.call(rbind,
replicate(6,
data.frame(x=1:60,y=cumsum(rnbinom(60,mu=20,size=0.1))),simplify=FALSE))
)
```

Below I roll through each group and create a data.frame, with another column called "highlight" to annotate the group of interest:

```
library(purrr)
library(ggthemes)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

unique(data$group) %>% 
map_dfr(~cbind(data,facet=.x,highlight=data$group %in% .x)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y,group=group))+
geom_line(aes(col=highlight)) + 
facet_wrap(~facet,ncol=3,scales="free") + 
theme_tufte() + scale_color_manual(values=c("#e5dfdf","#357376"))  +
theme(strip.text=element_text(size=12,colour="steelblue"))+
guides(colour = "none")
```

[image]

One can of course, create a list of ggplots, but in fact you are also replicating the data (ggplot creates a data.frame underneath):

```
plotfun = function(data,highlight){
data %>% 
mutate(highlight = group == highlight) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y,group=group))+
geom_line(aes(col=highlight)) + 
theme_tufte() + scale_color_manual(values=c("#e5dfdf","#357376"))  +
ggtitle(highlight)+ 
theme(plot.title = element_text(size=12,colour="steelblue"))+
guides(colour = "none")
}

grid.arrange(grobs=unique(data$group) %>% map(~plotfun(data,.x)),ncol=3)
```

[image]